rust-libp2p ping protocol is not sending equal no. of ping requests to connected nodes
I'm running a 4-node setup in docker and nodes are connected.
Node A, B, C & D
Issue:
Node A is trying to ping Node B,C,& D but getting different number of ping results:
Node B:18
Node C:6
Node D:6
Similarly some random numbers in other nodes as well.
Here is my network configuration:

    // Create a public/private key pair, either random or based on a seed.
    let local_peer_id = local_keys.public().to_peer_id();

    let _tcp_transport = libp2p::tokio_development_transport(local_keys.clone())?;

    let transport = tcp::tokio::Transport::new(tcp::Config::default().nodelay(true))
        .upgrade(upgrade::Version::V1)
        .authenticate(noise::Config::new(&local_keys).expect("signing libp2p-noise static keypair"))
        .multiplex(yamux::Config::default())
        .timeout(std::time::Duration::from_secs(20))
        .boxed();



    let ping_config = ping::Config::new()
    .with_interval(Duration::from_secs(10))
    .with_timeout(Duration::from_secs(30))
    .with_max_failures(NonZeroU32::new(10).expect("1 != 0"))
    .with_keep_alive(false);

    let swarm = {
        let mut behaviour = Behaviour {
            ping: ping::Behaviour::new(ping_config),
            identify: identify::Behaviour::new(identify::Config::new(
                "/ipfs/id/1.0.0".to_string(),
                local_keys.public(),
            )),
            // mdns: mdns::tokio::Behaviour::new(mdns::Config::default(), local_peer_id)?,
            kademlia: kademlia_behaviour(local_peer_id),
            gossipsub: gossipsub_behaviour(local_keys.clone(), topics)?,
            auto_nat: autonat_behaviour(local_peer_id, autonat_config),
        };


        SwarmBuilder::with_tokio_executor(transport, behaviour, local_peer_id).build()
    };


Is something missing in my config?
